# JavaScript IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Добрый день, почему на некоторых сайтах в IE javascrip'ты запускаются без проблем. А на мой скрипт

```
<script type='text/javascript'>    
function resize(){
    document.getElementById('bg-image').height = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById('page').style.marginLeft = (window.innerWidth -  
    document.getElementById('bg-image').width) / 2 + 'px';
}
window.onresize = resize;
window.onload = resize;
</script>
```

IE Пишет "Браузером Internet Explorer запрещено выполнение скриптов.... "

Comment: Мне кажется ответ очевиден и уже представлен в вопросе))

Comment: Так почему на некоторых не запрещено, а на моём запрещено?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, при заливке на хостинг всё заработало нормально. Всем спасибо.